# Update gradle version in a gitlab-ci build

Tags: java, gradle, continuous-integration, yaml, gitlab-ci

I've built a gitlab-ci yaml file, which works well. However the gradle version used in the image is different to that on my local machine. This is causing some unusual side effects, such as only some Java tests being run.

Here's my yaml file:

```
image: java:8-jdk
before_script:
  - echo `pwd`
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
  - rm -f  .gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock
  - rm -fr .gradle/caches/*/plugin-resolution/
cache:
  paths:
    - .gradle/wrapper
    - .gradle/caches
build:
  script:
    - ./gradlew build

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./gradlew test
    - cat build/jacocoHtml/index.html | grep -o 'Total[^%]*%'
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/jacocoHtml

      #deploy test coverage
pages:
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
    - test
  script:
    - mkdir public
    - mkdir public/jacoco
    - mv build/jacocoHtml/* public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - master
```

Currently, the build is being run on `4.10.3` but I need to update this to `5.1.1` to match my local setup.

Thanks in advance,

Sam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `gradle` [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/gradle) instead of `java:8-jdk`

For the version 5.1.1 with jdk8, use :

```
image: gradle:5.1.1-jdk8
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I also found it works by modifying the `distributionUrl` property in the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file